# Remove duplicate values from foreach

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have duplicated tasks in my database so I do not any duplicated Tasks with thir tags in my foreach

```
@foreach ($Tag->Tasks as $Task)


  <li> Task :: {{ $Task->task_name }} </li>
   @foreach ($Task->tasktags as $TaskTag)
  <li> Task Tags :: {{ $TaskTag->name }} </li>

   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: feels a tad too broad bud, able to expand on it?

Comment: who do you know that 2 tasks are equals?

Comment: what is the output do you want , as this is blade for loop , nothing to do with database removal of duplicate entries

Comment: Two things: Post your controller code and explain what field(s) do you use to know that the task is duplicated

Answer (score 1):

Use in your controller (before inserting parameter in view) `array_unique` function

More: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

If you have collection object:
https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-unique

Comment: this will not works because the data is an collection object

Answer (score 0):

See unique methods [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-unique)

```
@foreach ($Tag->Tasks as $Task)

   <li> Task :: {{ $Task->task_name }} </li>

   $uniqueTaskTags = $Task->tasktags->unique();

   @foreach ($uniqueTaskTags as $TaskTag)
      <li> Task Tags :: {{ $TaskTag->name }} </li>
   @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

use this no duplicate data will be print

```
{!! $Tag->Tasks = $Tag->Tasks->unique(); !!}
@foreach ($Tag->Tasks as $Task)
    <li> Task :: {{ $Task->task_name }} </li>
    {!! $Task->tasktags = $Task->tasktags->unique(); !!}
    @foreach ($Task->tasktags as $TaskTag)
        <li> Task Tags :: {{ $TaskTag->name }} </li>
    @endforeach
 @endforeach
```